# How to remove duplicates class objects from a set() in Python 2.7?

Tags: class, object, python-2.7, set, duplicates

Let's define a simple class:

```
class sample(object):
def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key
```

Let's say that a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 are objects of "sample" class (a1 and a5 share the same "key" element):

```
a1 = sample('test1')
a2 = sample('test2')
a3 = sample('test3')
a4 = sample('test4')
a5 = sample('test1')
```

Now, if I add these elements to a list this will be the result:

```
 [<__main__.sample at 0x1189c1e90>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c1b90>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c15d0>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c1dd0>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c16d0>]
```

But if I convert this list to a "set" object (to remove a1/a5) the result will be:

```
 {<__main__.sample at 0x1189c15d0>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c16d0>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c1b90>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c1dd0>,
 <__main__.sample at 0x1189c1e90>}
```

So, the question is: how can I modify the class so that it can set two objects that share the same "key" as the very same object (so I don't have duplicates in the set())? I'm looking for a very simple implementation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must implement your own `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods to ensure they are considered equal when constructing the set:

```
class Sample(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the `__hash__`, `__cmp__`, and `__eq__` methods. From the relevant [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__hash__#object.__hash__):

> ### hashable
>
> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a __hash__() method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an __eq__() or __cmp__() method).
>   Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.

In your implementation, you could just forward to the corresponding method of your key string.